# action not resulting on ng-click for button angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, spring-boot

I am developing a new library management software with spring boot,angular js, and MongoDB as backend. I want to perform crud operation  on MongoDB with that application and for that I referring some open source project  with that I can perform create and read operations successfully but can't perform delete and update operations so how can perform  I also made some changes for delete update but can't perform with that so tell me the changes have to perform in order to perform delete.I added this as my own in `mybooks.html` but the element is not deleting. For that, I made some changes in `mybooks.html` and `hello.js` for delete operation but the element is not getting deleted

```
// mybooks.html

 <h1>Your Current List of Books</h1>
  <style type="text/css">
     table { 
  margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
 }

table tr th, table tr td { 
  background: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 27px 74px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
}

table tr td { 
  background: #DDD;
  color: #47433F;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
</style>


 <table ng-controller="books">



  <tr>
      <th>BooK_id</th>
    <th>BooK_title</th>
    <th>BooK_author</th>        
    <th>BooK_year</th>
    <th>update</th>
 </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="message in controller.messages">
    <td>{{message.id}}</td>
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.author}}</td>     
    <td>{{message.year}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete" ng-click="remove(message.id)">
    </td>
 </tr>


</table>
```

changes made in controller in `hello.js` file

```
    /**
 * Created by sezin on 3/22/16.
 */
angular.module('hello', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller : 'home',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : 'navigation',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/register', {
            templateUrl : 'register.html',
            controller : 'register',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/mybooks', {
            templateUrl : 'mybooks.html',
            controller : 'books',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).otherwise('/'); 

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    })
    .controller('home', function($http, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data){
            self.greeting = data;

            self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");

            //self.messages = [];
            self.saveBook = function(){
                //var BookRecord = $resource('/account/', {username : self.currentUserName});
                //BookRecord.save(self.book);
                var request = {
                    userName: self.currentUserName,
                    title: self.book.title,
                    author: self.book.author,
                    year: self.book.year
                };
                $http.post('api/books/add', request).success(function(data){

                    if(data){
                        self.success = true;
                    } if(data == null){
                        self.success = false;
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                    //self.messages.push({type:'success', msg: 'Book Saved!'});
                }). error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            };






        });


    })
    .controller('books', function($http, $cookies){

        var self = this;
        self.messages = [];
        self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");

        $http.get('api/books/getAll/' + self.currentUserName).success(function(data){

            self.messages = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
        //run now 
      self.remove = function(messageId){
          console.log(" messageId :: "+messageId);
          $http.get('api/books/delete/'+messageId).success(function(data){

                // success 
           }). error(function(err){
                // error
           });

       };

    })

    .controller('navigation', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {
            var headers = credentials ? {authorization: "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)} :{};

            $http.get('/user/', {headers : headers}).success(function(data){
                if(data.name){
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.username = data.username;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }

                } else{
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }
                }
            })
        };

        authenticate();
        self.credentials = {};
        self.login = function(){
            authenticate(self.credentials, function () {
                if($rootScope.authenticated){
                    $location.path("/");
                    $rootScope.username = self.credentials.username;
                    $cookies.put("username", $rootScope.username);
                    self.error = false;
                } else{
                    $location.path("/login");
                    self.error = true;
                }

            });
        };

        self.logout = function(){
            $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function(){
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            });
        }
    })
    .controller('register', function($resource, $rootScope, $location){
        var self = this;
        self.register = function(){
            var User = $resource('/account');
            User.save(self.user, function(data){
                    self.success = data;


            });
        };

    });
```

changes in bookrestcontroller.java for delete-->

```
    package com.sezin.controller;

import com.sezin.model.Book;
import com.sezin.repository.BookRepository;
import com.sezin.repository.UserAccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sezin on 3/23/16.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookRestController {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByTitle/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Book getBookByTitle(@PathVariable String title){
        return repository.findByTitle(title);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByAuthor/{author}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable String author){
        return repository.findByAuthor(author);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/getAll/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByUserName(@PathVariable String userName){
        return repository.findByUserName(userName);
    }




    @RequestMapping(value ="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Book create(@RequestBody Book book){
        if( userAccountRepository.findByUsername(book.getUserName()) != null &&
                repository.findByTitle(book.getTitle()) == null){
            return repository.save(book);
        }
        else
            return null;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id){
        System.out.println("id :: "+id);

        Book book = repository.findById(id);

        if(book != null)
            repository.delete(book);
        else
            System.out.println("Book not exist ");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "{id}")
    public Book update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Book book){
        Book updated = repository.findOne(id);
        updated.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
        updated.setTitle(book.getTitle());
        updated.setYear(book.getyear());
        return repository.save(book);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try console.log() to check function remove is calling or not ?

Comment: I checked and not working,if you don't mind if you use TeamViewer can you see my code with I will give id come to discussion room I stuck badly with that from morning

Comment: What's the output from  console.log(" messageId :: "+messageId); are you seeing the messageid?

Comment: Can you assign `ng-controller="books"` to the main div of the page rather then input button ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on where this is failing? I see you have some logging - where do things fall apart?

Comment: Yes, per @Loading..it looks like you're referencing `messages` outside of a scope which is aware of `books` -- move the controller out to a wrapping element outside the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: see the updated mybooks.html

Comment: I don't see any difference. What works here? What doesn't work? Do you get a list of books?

Comment: I didn't see any logs in my output while running

Comment: yes I get the list of books but can't perform delete I am new to angular so please help me I had given GitHub project link and also given the changes I made in this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124648/discussion-between-ydworld-and-brendan).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your backend is working fine, try this

```
<table ng-controller="books">
    <tr>
        <th>BooK_id</th>
        <th>BooK_title</th>

<th>BooK_author</th>
            <th>BooK_year</th>
            <th>update</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="message in controller.messages">
            <td>{{message.id}}</td>
            <td>{{message.title}}</td>
            <td>{{message.author}}</td>
            <td>{{message.year}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete" ng-click="remove(message.id)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```js
angular.module("myapp", [])

.controller('books', function($http, $scope){
 
        var self = this;
        self.messages = [];
        self.currentUserName = 'asdasd'
       // Replace this code with your $http get method call
       $scope.messages = [{
             id: '123', title: 'hhh', author: 'asdasd', year: '1988'},{
             id: '456', title: 'fff', author: 'asdasd', year: '1988'},{
             id: '789', title: 'sss', author: 'asdasd', year: '1988'},{
             id: 'asdasd', title: 'asdasd', author: 'asdasd', year: '1988'}];
        //run now 
      $scope.remove = function(messageId){
          // Replace this code with your $http method call
          angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(item, index) {
            if(messageId === item.id) {
              console.log(index);
              $scope.messages.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });

       };

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>Your Current List of Books</h1>
  <style type="text/css">
     table { 
  margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
 }

table tr th, table tr td { 
  background: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 27px 74px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
}

table tr td { 
  background: #DDD;
  color: #47433F;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
</style>
<table ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="books">
   <tr>
     <th>BooK_id</th>
    <th>BooK_title</th>
    <th>BooK_author</th>        
    <th>BooK_year</th>
    <th>update</th>
 </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <td>{{message.id}}</td>
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.author}}</td>     
    <td>{{message.year}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete" ng-click="remove(message.id)">
    </td>
 </tr>


</table>
```

I've added a working copy of your front end code, with static data. If your backend works, this should work

**Tip:** To make your application RESTful, do use the `DELETE` HTTP verb to perform deletes :)

Comment: No, the DELETE is just a best practice that I was suggesting. Could you create a simple Snippet or JSFiddle and link us to it so that we can see what is happening?

Comment: Did you mean to specify `ng-controller="books as controller"`? Otherwise I'm not clear what `controller.messages` is meant to refer to.

Comment: Did you try what I posted? Can you show the updated code with the controller in the correct place?

Comment: I added ng-controller in tables and-and I am not good at angular so I didn't get what you're talking about delete

Comment: I have added a snippet with working code. Check it out

Comment: have look at this problem stackoverflow.com/q/48429456/4356983

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the way Angular bindings work, and in particular how they are scoped. It looks like you are trying to create a repeater (`ng-repeat`) on the `messages` prop before instantiating your controller.

Angular is currently trying to find `messages` on the applicable `scope` and coming up empty handed, so the repeater ends up being empty. As a result, your input is never rendered and the controller isn't initialized.

Move the `ng-controller` directive up to the `table` element, or wrap the while table in a `div` with a controller.

You might also want to switch to a better convention for scope-control with the [ControllerAs](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) notation: use `ng-controller="books as bookCtrl"` in the container and on the input you'd use `ng-click="bookCtrl.remove(message.id)"`.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? I'm not going to be opening code from unknown sources, sorry. Also you should be working through this yourself.

Comment: but I can load and see book entries I will give full code snapshots one minute

Comment: have look at this problem stackoverflow.com/q/48429456/4356983